# Build widgets in an Edit Screen with riverpod

Tags: flutter, riverpod, riverpod-generator, modal-sheet

https://i.stack.imgur.com/qYUwW.png

I am working on an edit screen for editing an existing habit.

A habit has a color and I need to pass the old or previous color of the current habit to be edited to a `color_selector` modal sheet such that if the habit’s color is purple, once I click this widget, purple should be pre - selected.

How can I achieve this.

Here’s the controller code for selecting the colors when creating a new habit.

```dart
/// Notifier class for exposing a habit's color state.
@riverpod
class SelectColorNotifier extends _$SelectColorNotifier {
  @override
  // use the last selected color when re-opening the color modal.
  int build() => ref.watch(newColorProvider);

  void updateColor(int selectedColor) {
    if (selectedColor == state) return;
    state = selectedColor;
  }
}

/// Notifier class for keeping track of the selected color
/// from `selectColorNotifierProvider`.
///
/// Used to set the selected color from the color modal only when the save icon
/// is pressed.
@riverpod
class NewColor extends _$NewColor {
  @override
  int build() => habitColors.first;

  void updateNewColor(int newColor) {
    if (newColor == state) return;
    state = newColor;
  }
}
```

The `color_selector` widget code:

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_riverpod/flutter_riverpod.dart';
import 'package:habitin/src/common_widgets/rounded_padding.dart';
import 'package:habitin/src/constants/constants.dart';
import 'package:habitin/src/features/add_edit/view/new_habit_controller.dart';

class ColorSelector extends StatelessWidget {
  const ColorSelector({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return GestureDetector(
      onTap: () => showColorModalSheet(context),
      child: RoundedPadding(
        vertical: 8,
        horizontal: 8,
        child: Row(
          mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
          children: [
            Consumer(
              builder: (_, ref, __) {
                final selectedColor = ref.watch(newColorProvider);
                return RoundedPadding(
                  vertical: 6,
                  horizontal: 6,
                  radius: 14,
                  color: Theme.of(context).colorScheme.onSecondary,
                  child: Container(
                    height: 38,
                    width: 40,
                    decoration: BoxDecoration(
                      shape: BoxShape.circle,
                      color: Color(selectedColor),
                    ),
                  ),
                );
              },
            ),
            gapW16,
            Text("COLOR", style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.bodySmall)
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  Future<void> showColorModalSheet(BuildContext context) {
    return showModalBottomSheet(
      enableDrag: false,
      isScrollControlled: true,
      isDismissible: false,
      context: context,
      builder: (_) => Container(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(20),
        child: Column(
          mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
          children: [
            Row(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
              children: [
                IconButton(
                  icon: const Icon(Icons.close_rounded),
                  onPressed: () => Navigator.pop(context),
                ),
                Text(
                  "Select Color",
                  style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.bodyLarge,
                ),
                Consumer(
                  builder: (_, ref, __) {
                    return IconButton(
                      icon: const Icon(Icons.check_rounded),
                      onPressed: () {
                        final selectedColor =
                            ref.read(selectColorNotifierProvider);
                        ref
                            .read(newColorProvider.notifier)
                            .updateNewColor(selectedColor);
                        Navigator.pop(context);
                      },
                    );
                  },
                ),
              ],
            ),
            gapH30,
            Wrap(
              spacing: 28.0,
              runSpacing: 20.0,
              children:
                  habitColors.map((color) => ColorChip(color: color)).toList(),
            ),
            gapH20,
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

/// Builds the individual Color Chip widgets used in [ColorSelector].
class ColorChip extends StatelessWidget {
  const ColorChip({super.key, required this.color, this.oldColor});

  final int color;
  final int? oldColor;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Consumer(
      builder: (_, ref, __) {
        final selectedColor = ref.watch(selectColorNotifierProvider);
        return GestureDetector(
          onTap: () =>
              ref.read(selectColorNotifierProvider.notifier).updateColor(color),
          child: Container(
            height: 60,
            width: 60,
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
              shape: BoxShape.circle,
              color: Color(color),
              border: selectedColor == color
                  ? Border.all(
                      width: 3.0,
                      color: Theme.of(context).colorScheme.onBackground,
                    )
                  : const Border(),
            ),
            child: selectedColor == color
                ? const Icon(Icons.check_rounded)
                : const SizedBox.shrink(),
          ),
        );
      },
    );
  }
}
```

I have tried the usual way of converting `ColorSelector` to a statefulWidget and passing the `oldColor` in its `initState` but this breaks the rebuild when selecting a new color.

I am also thinking of passing the `oldColor` as an argument to the `selectedColorNotifierProvider` such that if the user is in **Edit Mode**, the initial state of this provider should be that old color. This hasn't worked correctly so far.

```dart
/// Notifier class for exposing a habit's color state.
@riverpod
class SelectColorNotifier extends _$SelectColorNotifier {
  @override
  // use the last selected color when re-opening the color modal.
  int build() => ref.watch(newColorProvider);

  void updateColor(int selectedColor) {
    if (selectedColor == state) return;
    state = selectedColor;
  }
}

/// Notifier class for keeping track of the selected color
/// from `selectColorNotifierProvider`.
///
/// Used to set the selected color from the color modal only when the save icon
/// is pressed.
@riverpod
class NewColor extends _$NewColor {
  @override
  // set the initial state to be the current habit color.
  int build(int? oldColor) => oldColor ?? habitColors.first;

  void updateNewColor(int newColor) {
    if (newColor == state) return;
    state = newColor;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Solved this by passing the `oldColor` to the color providers in the controller class.

The new controller class looks like this:

```dart
/// Notifier class for exposing a habit's color state.
@riverpod
class SelectColorNotifier extends _$SelectColorNotifier {
  @override
  // use the last selected color when re-opening the color modal.
  // we also need to pass the existing habit color to this provider.
  int build(int? oldColor) => ref.watch(newColorProvider(oldColor));
  

  void updateColor(int selectedColor) {
    if (selectedColor == state) return;
    state = selectedColor;
  }
}

/// Notifier class for keeping track of the selected color
/// from `selectColorNotifierProvider`.
///
/// Used to set the selected color from the color modal when the save icon
/// is pressed.
@riverpod
class NewColor extends _$NewColor {
  @override
  // pass the existing habit color to the initial state of the provider.
  int build(int? oldColor) => oldColor ?? habitColors.first;
  

  void updateNewColor(int newColor) {
    if (newColor == state) return;
    state = newColor;
  }
}
```

Then watch this provider in the concerned widgets with:
`final selectedColor = ref.watch(newColorProvider(oldColor));`

`oldColor` is passed to the widget via the constructor.

```dart
class ColorSelector extends ConsumerWidget {
  const ColorSelector({super.key, this.oldColor});
  final int? oldColor;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context, WidgetRef ref) {
    final selectedColor = ref.watch(newColorProvider(oldColor));
    return /*...*/
}
```